cifs mount folders appear empty after accessing files
TL/DR
linux cifs mount of windows server 2019 share succeeds.
At first the mount seems ok, but after accessing some files the directories appear empty from the linux site. looking at the windows side all files are still present.
after umount and mount it looks fine again
We don't see any relevant errors in logs.
This setup used to work without issue, we have no idea what changed
No updates on windows or linux were done.
Any help, hint, ... welcome
More details
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
samba-4.4.4-9.el7.x86_64
/etc/auto.mnt contains
mountname -fstype=cifs,vers=3.0,credentials=/root/.ssh/smb.auth,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 ://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/sharename

found  https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/LinuxCIFS_troubleshooting that may be helpful
